# Why am I sometimes spontaneously presented with an SSL certificate from my U-Verse Residential Gateway?

Tags: tls, man-in-the-middle, internet

Sometimes, we will experience a brief "hiccup" in our AT&T UVerse internet service. When this happens, and a user happens to be surfing the web at the same time, we will suddenly be presented with this:

[image: SSL Certificate]

This will actually come from the website that the user is on, such as Gmail, or any other HTTPS website. When I click "View Certificate:"

[image: attlocal.net Gateway Authentication cert]

[image: attlocal.net Gateway Authentication cert]

Can someone explain to me what is going on here? Is there any explanation for this behavior that *isn't* nefarious? I mean... I'm often reminded of the quote that one should not attribute to malice what can be written off as incompetence, but... doesn't this look really sketchy? Could I be exposing otherwise encrypted data to AT&T because of this?

Comment: Well, what certificate is being used when this *doesn't* occur? Who signs Google, Facebook, etc. when you browse there normally? Whats the cert path?

Comment: During normal operation, the cert path to Gmail, just as an example, is exactly what you'd expect it to be... like GeoTrust Global CA -> Google Internet Authority G2 -> mail.google.com. But then the AT&T Uverse router glitches and my browser gets presented with a new certificate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rg is trying to get you to look at a different page by hijacking the one you were headed to.  Similar to the way some WiFi gateways will force a redirect to an auth page by hijaçkong the first thing you try to access on 80 or 443.  Att does this fptr different reasons, like when they were pushing bittorrent users to pages trying to promote paid video and music services.